# Symfony Compiler Pass : error when adding a doctrine filter

Tags: symfony

I want to add a doctrine filter with a `CompilerPass` in a bundle that I created.

I tried this and **I think the filter is added** (because I call dump() in `FilterCollection` : `enable()` function is called).

```
class UserCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container): void
    {

        $container->getDefinition('doctrine.orm.default_configuration')
            ->addMethodCall('addFilter', [
                'deleted_at',
                DeletedAtFilter::class,
            ])
        ;

        $container->getDefinition('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager')
            ->addMethodCall('getFilters', [], true)
            ->addMethodCall('enable', [
                'deleted_at',
            ])
        ;
```

But now, I have this error :

> Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\ManagerConfigurator::configure() must implement interface Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface, instance of Doctrine\ORM\Query\FilterCollection given

I think `->addMethodCall('getFilters', [], true)` replaces the original class of the `doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager` service. Do you know how to avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter on `addMethodCall` instructs the DI compiler to use the return value of the call as the service instance from that point.

As you can see in the signature of the method:

`addMethodCall(string $method, array $arguments = [], bool $returnsClone = false)`

where the third parameter is explicitly documented with "Whether the call returns the service instance or not".

If you have to call the `enable` method on the FilterCollection you have to decorate the configurator service and call the `enable` method from there.